# как добавить в лист элемент из другого листа с определённым индексом

Tags: python, python-3.x

babynames2000s.txt(неполный):

```
1   Jacob   273,450 Emily   223,488
2   Michael 250,174 Madison 192,976
3   Joshua  231,602 Emma    181,055
4   Matthew 221,266 Olivia  155,848
5   Daniel  203,404 Hannah  155,525
6   Christopher 203,006 Abigail 150,746
7   Andrew  202,208 Isabella    149,310
8   Ethan   201,611 Samantha    134,148
9   Joseph  194,377 Elizabeth   133,166
10  William 194,079 Ashley  132,934
```

в первом столбце находятся мужские имена.
задача записывать в новый лист boysfile элементы из listfile начиная с первого индекса и далее через 3.

```
infile = open("babynames2000s.txt", "r") 
outfile_boys = open("boynames2014.txt", "w")
outfile_girls = open("girlnames2014.txt", "w")

listfile = []
lines = infile.read().split('\t')
indexx = 1
boysfile = []

for line in lines:
    listfile.append(line.rstrip())

print(listfile[indexx])
for item in listfile:
    boysfile = listfile[indexx]
    indexx = indexx + 3
outfile_boys.write(boysfile) 

print(boysfile)
```

выдаёт:

Jacob

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/spart/Documents/python/homework4/boys_and_girls.py", line
>   15, in  boysfile = listfile[indexx]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

так же пытался вместо `boysfile = listfile[indexx]` , использовать `boysfile.append(listfile[indexx])`
выдавало ту же самую ошибку

Comment: Вы что-то странное пытаетесь сделать. Вы понимаете, что у вас indexx будет расти на 3 за каждый элемент в listfile, и когда вы дойдёте примерно до трети этого списка, indexx превысит максимальный размер listfile?

Comment: boys_list = [l.strip().split() for l in infile.readlines()][1::3]

Answer (score 0):

Если я все понял правильно то должно быть так:

```
for item in listfile[0::3]: # Начнет с первого элемента (0 это первый элемент списка) с шагом 3 
    boysfile.append(item)
```